# Как запустить файл с рабочего стола?

Tags: ubuntu

Есть файл на рабочем столе.

> $ file dash-qt
>       dash-qt: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=43eb2b921a6519a2d2de1f30969182f597a13ac7, stripped

Я без проблем запускаю его из терминала командой `./dash-qt`

Как запустить его двойным щелчком по иконке?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

попробуйте создать там же файл с произвольным именем, содержащим суффикс `.desktop` (`bla.bla.desktop`, например) и с таким содержимым:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=blablabla
Exec="/полный/путь/к/вашему/файлу/dash-qt"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

если программа требует для работы эмулятор терминала, замените в соответствующей строчке *false* на *true*.

вот по этому файлу и «щёлкайте дважды».

**дополнение**: вроде бы, нынче некоторые «особо умные» de (desktop environments) начинают «вставлять палки в колёса», сообщая какой-то бред про «запуск недоверенной программы» (или что-то в этом духе), если у данного файла не стоит битов исполнимости. потому, на всякий случай, лучше их поставить:

```
$ chmod +x bla.bla.desktop
```

**дополнение 2**: можно сделать и без desktop-файла, манипулируя *mime-типами*: [Запустить исполняемый файл в kubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701235/178576)

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось! Хочу еще добавить что необходимо дать права на исполнение данного файла chmod +x blablabla