# Запустить исполняемый файл в kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

Не могу запустить исполняемую GUI программу, предлагает выбрать другую чтобы открыть этот файл.
При этом, она спокойно запускается из консоли(./Program).
Хочу запустить исполняемую программу(не ярлык) из Dolphin.
**Реально ли, не создавая таковой для каждого исполняемого файла, запускать этот самый файл прямиком из файлового менеджера(упомянутого выше Dolphin).**

```
egor@kubuntu:~/Рабочий стол$ ls -l
итого 1024
-rw-r--r-- 1 egor egor    2353 июл 28 12:50 Home.desktop
-rwxrwxr-x 1 egor egor 1038816 авг  2 23:34 Program
-rw-r--r-- 1 egor egor    2757 июл 28 12:50 trash.desktop
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запустить файл с рабочего стола?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494110/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Не совсем, подкорректировал вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

процедура с созданием desktop-файла описана здесь: [Как запустить файл с рабочего стола?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494110/178576)

---

> не создавая desktop-файл для каждого исполняемого файла, запускать этот самый файл прямиком из файлового менеджера

на основании этого ответа: [How to force Dolphin to not execute executable files](https://askubuntu.com/a/179192/416190)

и на примере с файлом `/usr/bin/gimp-2.8`:

1. нам надо определить *mime-тип* файла:

   ```
   $ mimetype /usr/bin/gimp-2.8
   /usr/bin/gimp-2.8: application/x-sharedlib
   ```
2. смотрим секцию про `application/x-sharedlib` во *freedesktop*-овском описании типов:

   ```
   $ sed -n '/mime-type.*"application\/x-sharedlib"/,/\/mime-type/p' /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
   ```

   получаем это описание (несущественные строки опущены):

   ```
     <mime-type type="application/x-sharedlib">
       <comment>shared library</comment>
   ...
     </mime-type>
   ```
3. чтобы файл с таким *mime-типом* считался исполнимым, можно сделать его подклассом `application/x-executable`, добавив строку про *sub-class*:

   ```
     <mime-type type="application/x-sharedlib">
       <sub-class-of type="application/x-executable"/>
       <comment>shared library</comment>
   ...
     </mime-type>
   ```

   перед внесением изменений, естественно, имеет смысл сделать резервную копию файла.
4. чтобы изменения в файле `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` были применены в текущую базу данных *mime-типов*, можно воспользоваться скриптом `update-mime-database`, передав ему параметром путь к каталогу с файлами, один из которых мы меняли:

   ```
   $ sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
   ```

проверил на *nautilus*-е: работает.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.