# Как запустить двойным клико .run файл (сделанный через "makeself") с графического рабочего стола на linux?

Tags: linux, makefile

Начну с того что дело видимо не в правах на выполнение(любой гугловый запрос подскажет именно это)
Есть файл с расширением ".run", сделанный с помощью "makeself".

Запускаю из терминала - всё ок.

Запускаю двойным кликом с рабочего стола получаю в лучшем случае модальное окно с выбором по типу "что сделать?"(Alt10), в худшем система пытается его открыть каким-нибудь своим текстовым редактором и подвисает(Ubuntu16), в зависимости от ОС.

Можно ли как-то обмануть систему и просто запускать файл, может свойство какое указать.
Желательно как то решить на уровне файла, а не для конкретной ОС.

```
   user@ubuntu16:~$ file ./Desktop/test.run 
    ./Desktop/test.run: POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
    user@ubuntu16:~$ ll ./Desktop/test.run 
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25969666 янв 24 15:33 ./Desktop/test.run*
```

Comment: [например, так, только "terminal=true"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494125/178576)

Answer (score 1):

> получаю в лучшем случае модальное окно с выбором по типу "что
> сделать?"

Это означает, что файловый менеджер (не знаю, какой конкретно у Вас) не знает, что делать с этим файлом. По умолчанию, большинство ФМ понимает двойной клик как команду "Open". Однако понятно, что файлы разных типов нужно открывать разными программами. Вот ФМ и спрашивает Вас, чем открывать файл с расширением run?

Однако, из этого правила есть исключение: "исполнимые" файлы. Если файл будет признан исполнимым, то ФМ попытается его запустить, а не открывать. Для признания файла исполнимым необходимо выполнение двух условий:

1. Файл в его атрибутах должен иметь "1" хотя бы в одном из разрядов "х". Типичный набор атрибутов исполняемого файла выгладит так: 0755.
2. Файл в битах свойств которого есть хотя бы один бит выполняемости, должен либо иметь структуру ELF (Двоичный исполняемый код линукса), либо быть файлом, в первой строке которого задана программа, которая "умеет" выполнять такие файлы. Например, для python программ эта строка может выглядеть так: *#!/usr/bin/env python3*

Но и из этого правила есть исключение. Если конкретная установка Linux имеет GUI оболочку, то в домашней директории каждого конкретного пользователя будет папка с названием *.local/share/applications* в которой лежат т.н. desktop-файлы. Сразу надо сказать, что всё дальнейшее сильно зависит от конкретного дистрибутива и конкретного дисплейного менеджера - Gnome, KDE... Но, в ощих чертах, происходит следующее:

1. При входе пользователя сканируется эта папка и выбирается информация из них. Эти файлы содержат информацию о том, какую иконку нужно показывать на рабочем столе, как отображать эту программу в меню и ещё очень много других настроек.
2. Формируется рабочий стол и системное меню. Для этого очень важно наличие в destop файлах параметров *Exec* и *Icon*. Но, повторяю, всё это очень специфично для разных дистрибутивов и разных ДМ. Например, в Fedora Gnome рабочего стола, как такового, нет совсем. А файлы desktop используются только для формирования меню.
3. После этого можно будет дважды щёлкнув по иконке на рабочем столе (или выбрав пункт в меню), заставить ДМ попытаться проанализировать соответствующий desktop-файл и выполнить программу, указанную в параметре *Exec*.

Но и из этого правила есть исключение :-)

В папку *Desktop* можно набросать и обычных файлов (что я бы не стал делать), которые будут отображаться на рабочем столе в соотвествии с правилами и настройками конретного **файлового** менеджера. По умолчанию, к примеру, в большинстве файловых менеджеров задано, что файлы jpg нужно открывать с помощью утилиты просмотра картинок. Какой именно утилитой - вы можете задать в настройках Вашего файлового менеджера.

У Вас есть файл с расширением *run* с которым файловый менеджер не знает, что делать. Для того, что бы сообщить ФМ о том, что файлы *run* нужно запускать, выберите этот файл, щёлкните по нему правой мышкой и в появивемся меню "Открыть с помощью" выберите пункт "Запустить как программу". После этого должно появится окошко с вопросом вроде "Сделать это дефаультным поведением?", на которое Вы ответите "Да".

И будет Вам счастье :-)

Comment: маленькая подсказка: если возникают проблемы с написанием иностранных слов (например: «в стране объявили дефолт, мы живём в преддефолтном состоянии, а мне всё по-дефолту»), то можно попробовать заменить слово его переводом (например, «сделать это поведением по-умолчанию»).